# Not able to track change in input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

In the template I have a input element.

```
<input class='qq-edit-caption-selector qq-edit-caption kk-editing' placeholder='Enter Caption here ...' onkeypress='captionUpdate();'>
```

I want to track the change in the input value,and enable the Update button.Tried below options:

- `onkeypress='captionUpdate();'`
- Tried jquery change or click on the class

```js
$('.qq-edit-caption').change(function() {
    alert('qq-edit-caption');        
});
```

Both options does not get fired up!!not sure I have anything issues with my setup or Fine Uploader does not allow that? Please see my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCMDP.jpg):

[image]

Any way to solve this problem with FU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply adding this inline event handler directly to the template element, then it's not surprising that it's never triggered. Fine Uploader templates are quite primitive in that the template is interpreted as an HTML string and then used to create DOM elements inside of your container element (the element referenced as [your `element` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#element)).

You really should never use inline event handlers. There are quite a few disadvantages to this approach. I talk about this in more depth in my book - [Beyond jQuery](https://leanpub.com/beyondjquery). And the method of attaching event handlers is not necessary at all in your case, as far as I can tell. Instead, after constructing a new instance of Fine Uploader, simply attach an event handler of your choice to the input element using `addEventListener`. For example if your `<input>` element is given a CSS class name of 'qq-edit-caption', you can attach a "change" event handler like this:

```
var uploadContainer = document.querySelector('#my-uploader')

var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
   element: uploadContainer
   ...
})

uploadContainer.querySelector('.qq-edit-caption')
  .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      // event handler logic here...
   })
```

...and if you are creating this input element for each file and need to attach a "change" handler to *all* of these input elements, you should attach a single delegated event handler to the container element, and react based on the element that initially triggered the event (look at the `target` property of the event). You can determine the ID of the file by looking at the CSS class of the parent `<li>` of the `event.target`, or you can look for a 'qq-file-id' attribute on the parent `<li>` of the target element (the value will be the file ID). That code might look something like this:

```
var uploadContainer = document.querySelector('#my-uploader')

var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
   element: uploadContainer
   ...
})

uploadContainer.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      if (event.target.className.indexOf('qq-edit-caption') >= 0) {
         var fileId = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('qq-file-id'))
         // ...
      }
   })
```

Comment: Thanks Ray. That makes lot of sense why my code not triggered; let me experiment your suggestion and see where I can take this. Will update soon.....

Comment: Ray's advice worked for me but I could not get qq-file-id attribute from my input element. I had to navigate out of current element to find the update button element and then disable the button. ex: updateButton = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.file-section-button');

Comment: @bizready You can get the file ID for any file element or file element child/descendant element using [the `getId` Fine Uploader UI method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getId).

Comment: I tried... UpdateButton = qq(uploader.getId(event.target)).getByClass('file-section-button')[0]; and it gave me error -> s3.fine-uploader.min.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: b.getAttribute is not a function

Comment: Then there is an error in your code somewhere. I'm not sure why you would expect the container element to have a CSS class of 'file-section-button'.

Comment: That is because I am applying different css  (see original screenshot in the first post) so that it can look like "select files", otherwise it would look like http://imgur.com/k5UFkW2.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```js
$('.inp input').keyup(function(){
   if (this.value.length > 0) {
     $(this).closest('.row').find('.cell.btn button.upload').prop('disabled', false);
   }else{
     $(this).closest('.row').find('.cell.btn button.upload').prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

```css
* {position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}
.row{overflow:hidden;}
  .cell{float:left;height:40px;}
    .pic{width:82px;}
    .inp{width:230px;}
      .inp input{font-size:1rem;padding:2px 5px;}
    .btn{width:60px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell pic">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/40">
  </div>
  <div class="cell inp">
    <input class='qq-edit-caption-selector qq-edit-caption kk-editing' placeholder='Enter Caption...'>
  </div>
  <div class="cell btn">
    <button class="upload" disabled>Upload</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cell btn">
    <button class="del" disabled>Delete</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- .row -->
```

Comment: This won't work - you must escape reserved characters in selector strings (such as a dot) with a double-backslash.

Comment: @Gibberish - Thanks for he detailed response with working code.I tried same in my project setup and it did not work, which means, there may be issues with my local environment or may be some kind of conflict with File Uploader platform/library.

Comment: @RayNicholus - what you mean by ' escape reserved characters in selector strings with a double-backslash' ?

Comment: If the CSS class contains a dot, for example, you must prefix that dot with "\\". So `find('.cell.btn button.upload')` must be expressed as `find('.cell\\.btn button\\.upload')`

Answer (score 0):

You can enable and disable the state of button by the input value.Using the Keyup function

```
 $('.qq-edit-caption').keyup(function() {
       if(this.value.length > 0){
            $("#edit").prop('disabled', false);
       }
       else {
        $("#edit").prop('disabled', true);
       }
    });
```

Comment: Hi there! I think the main issue here is selecting the input element. Though it is not obvious at all - the problem is that the OP is trying to select the element before the library adds it to the DOM. I detailed why this may be happening in my answer. But i'll admit - I'm not really sure if the OP needs keyup or change as an event handler in this case. The former _may_ be more appropriate, but perhaps a change event handler may also be more appropriate to prevent code from unnecessarily executing on each keypress.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the onchange event? Does it work?

```
<input class='qq-edit-caption-selector qq-edit-caption kk-editing' placeholder='Enter Caption here ...' onchange='captionUpdate();'>
```