# How to define extra button in fine uploader template that will trigger its own end action

Tags: fine-uploader

I want to have 
- a text field and a button. Upon click of button text data will need to posted to endpoint.

The text field and button will repeat for each file in the uploader.

Below my attempt, and it is not working properly in all the cases and want to get to better solution.

The text field: qq-edit-caption
The button:  qq-upload-update-caption
The button acts as delete button with selector 'qq-upload-delete-selector' and to differentiate I set a flag true on the onclick action (crappy I know!). 
I read lot about creating 'extraButton' and all it talks about(as per my understanding) creating additional upload button, buy I need button on each file like DELETE and CANCEL,and not sure how I can cleanly implement the solution. Any help is much appreciated.

My template

```
<div class='qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader' qq-drop-area-text='Drop files here'>
    <div class='qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container'>
        <div role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='0' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' class='qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area' qq-hide-dropzone>
        <span class='qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='buttons'>
        <div class='qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button'>
            <div>Select files</div>
        </div>
        <button type='button' id='trigger-upload-section<?php echo $ind; ?>' class='btn btn-primary file-section-button'>
            <i class='icon-upload icon-white'></i> Upload
        </button>
    </div>
    <span class='qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing'>
        <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
        <span class='qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner'></span>
    </span>
    <ul class='qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list' aria-live='polite' aria-relevant='additions removals'>
        <li>
            <div class='qq-progress-bar-container-selector'>
                <div role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='0' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' class='qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar'></div>
            </div>
            <span class='qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner'></span>

            <div class="filewrapper">              
              <div class="filecontainer">
                <div class="filecontent">
                  <img class='qq-thumbnail-selector' qq-max-size='80' qq-server-scale>                                
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file filename"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="filesidebar">
                <!--span class='qq-upload-caption-selector qq-upload-caption'></span-->
                <!--span class='qq-edit-caption-icon-selector qq-edit-caption-icon kk-editable' aria-label='Edit caption'></span-->                    
                <input class='qq-edit-caption-selector qq-edit-caption kk-editing' placeholder='Enter Caption here ...' onchange='captionUpdate();'>
              </div>
              <div class="filesidebar2">
                <button type='button' class='qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-update-caption file-section-button btn-primary' onclick='captionUpdate(true);' title='Caption Update' disabled><i class='icon-pencil icon-white'></i></button>
                <button type='button' class='qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel'>Cancel</button>
                <button type='button' class='qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry'>Retry</button>
                <button type='button' class='qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete file-section-button btn-primary' onclick='captionUpdate(false);' title='Delete File'><i class='icon-trash icon-white'></i></button>

              </div>
              <span role='status' class='qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text'></span>
              <div class="fileclear"></div>           
            </div>  
        </li>
    </ul>

    <dialog class='qq-alert-dialog-selector'>
        <div class='qq-dialog-message-selector'></div>
        <div class='qq-dialog-buttons'>
            <button type='button' class='qq-cancel-button-selector'>Close</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>

    <dialog class='qq-confirm-dialog-selector'>
        <div class='qq-dialog-message-selector'></div>
        <div class='qq-dialog-buttons'>
            <button type='button' class='qq-cancel-button-selector'>No</button>
            <button type='button' class='qq-ok-button-selector'>Yes</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>

    <dialog class='qq-prompt-dialog-selector'>
        <div class='qq-dialog-message-selector'></div>
        <input type='text'>
        <div class='qq-dialog-buttons'>
            <button type='button' class='qq-cancel-button-selector'>Cancel</button>
            <button type='button' class='qq-ok-button-selector'>Ok</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>
</div>
```

Caption Update Button Click:

```
uploaderContainer.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            isCaptionUpdateClick = false;
            if (event.target.className.indexOf('icon-pencil') >= 0) {
                isCaptionUpdateClick = true;
            };
        });
```

My Delete Parameter setup:

```
deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,              
            method: "POST",        
            endpoint: "/ci/fine/endpoint",        
            params: {
                qqcaptionupdate: function() {                   
                    if (isCaptionUpdateClick === true) {
                        return 'YES'; 
                    }
                },
                qqcaption: function() { 
                    return captionValue; 
                },
                bookid: function() { 
                    return $("#book_id").val();
                },
                sectionid: function() { 
                    return $('#'+uploaderInfo.sectionIdSelector+'').val();
                },
            }        
        }
```

Comment: You're using inline event handlers, which I advised against in an answer to another very similar question of yours in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043881/not-able-to-track-change-in-input-value. Please reread my answer.

Comment: I have updated my question to explain my issue. Please see my logic to capture caption update user click, and I want to use isCaptionUpdateClick in param setup of deleteFile; If qqcaptionupdate==YES (server-side), I will update the caption, otherwise it will go to File Delete!. Now my issues is that onDelete: is executed before user's click event on the caption update  button. So, isCaptionUpdateClick false and File get Deleted rather than caption update. Is there any other way to set isCaptionUpdateClick flag before FU triggers delete events such as onDelete....?

Comment: "it is not working properly" - what does this mean?

Comment: my apologies Ray; I did re-factor based on your previous response and added specific delete param so server indeed get flag for clicking CaptionButton; that resolved my issue; 'It is not working properly' - my CaptionUpdate click not doing it job, instead it was Deleting. Thought, I would ask here to get reasonable solution without having to implement the inline onclick action - thought that was the culprit as you indicated earlier that using inline statement may be troublesome. Thought it is not great solution,it works now! thanks for your help.